# javascript validation. what am I doing wrong here?

Tags: javascript

I am new in JS and I am trying to do the simplest validation here and I cannot get it to work :/ basically when I press Submit I want either ERROR text in the div below the form or an echo text from the php file. Whats wrong with it? I really dnt know what I am doing wrong please help

```
<form name="myform" id="myform" method="post" action="echo.php">
<label for="username">User Name:</label><br />
<input type="text" id="username" name="username" /><br />
<label for="password">Password</label><br />
<input type="text" name="password" /><br />
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Send">
</form>
<div id="errorMessages"></div>
```

And JS code:

```
window.onload = function(){
validateForm();
}

function validateForm(){

document.getElementById("myform").onsubmit = function(){

    if (document.getElementById("username") == ""){
        document.getElementById("errorMessages").innerHTML = "ERROR";
        return false;
        }
    else return true;
};
}
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? If not, what is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (document.getElementById("username").value){
    document.getElementById("errorMessages").innerHTML = "ERROR";
    return false;
}
else { 
    return true;
}
```

Pay attention that `document.getElementById` returns the instance of the DOM element found on the page. So use the `.value` property. Also you do not really need to compare strings with empty string in JavaScript so get rid of `== ""`.

Answer (score 4):

`document.getElementById("username")` is a DOM element.
As long as the element exists, it will never fuzzily equal `""`.

You probably want `.value`, which returns the value of the textbox.

Comment: If you don't understand what he means by "fuzzily" look into javascript `==` vs `===`

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct js:

```
window.onload = function(){
validateForm();
}

function validateForm(){

document.getElementById("myform").onsubmit = function(){

    if (document.getElementById("username").value == ""){
        document.getElementById("errorMessages").innerHTML = "ERROR";
        return false;
        }
    else return true;
};
}
```

there was a ".value" missing after document.getElementById("username")